# Django - specify column order on dynamic model

Tags: django-models

Say we create a Model like this:

```
def model_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    attrs = {}
    attrs['Meta'] = type('Meta', (object,), {
        'verbose_name': 'My Dynamic model',
        'db_table': 'dynamic_model_table'
    })    

    # Ex. add an arbitrary fields
    attrs['username'] = models.CharField(
        max_length = 128,
        db_column = 'username'
    )
    attrs['email'] = models.CharField(
        max_length = 128,
        db_column = 'email'
    )

    return type('DynamicModel', (models.Model,), attrs)
```

How do I specify the column order in the database? I.e the CREATE statement must be

```
CREATE TABLE "dynamic_model_table" (
    "username" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(128) NOT NULL
)
```

Using the code example however, the column order will be random.

Comment: Queries don't care about the column order...

Comment: That is true, but my eye does.